# Check if special messages received from data stream

Tags: java

I'm receiving continuously data streams of log messages. In each data stream there are some special messages representing states.

Now I want to track if all states reached until the data stream ends. And if not, which state reached at last.

I don't know how to implement that efficiently. I was thinking to use two lists. One static list in which all possible states are stored. And one dynamic list where I can add all currently receiving states within the current data stream. So that I can check each message, if the message is in the static list, than I can add it to the dynamic list.

And when data stream ends, I can see which states I received and which states are missing. For the next data stream I can clear the dynamic list and start again.

Is that an general way to do something like that? Or do you know a more efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Focusing on your performance concern)

I am not sure if I understood your problem constraints, but despite the fact this is obviously implying an online algorithm, there is this assumption that can help a lot towards a simple and efficient implementation:

the assumption is you know upfront the set of all possible distinct messages that may (or may not) be coming from your input stream -- so that:

(pardon the pseudo code below, it's just I prefer that my rusty Java doesn't get in the way so incorrect that it would be confusing and obscure the idea; but I may give a shot at a C# version some time later if there is interest in that)

**Init phase**

1) in a first pair of maps, build once and for all a perfect hash function (in fact, a bijection, also) of your message corpus (say, keyed with a simple integer key):

(cache of, say, "mapBy" function / direction; in signature notation)

```
mapBy : Integer -> Message
```

i.e.,

```
1 -> message 1

2 -> message 2

etc...
```

and,

(cache of inverse of "mapBy", aka "hashOf" function / direction)

```
hashOf : Message -> Integer
```

i.e.,

```
message 1 -> 1

message 2 -> 2

etc...
```

Of course, the construction / initialization of mapBy is trivial, as you just enumerate all the messages that are known, and assign a distinct integer key to each of them (zero or one-based key, or negative, even, that doesn't matter here -- it's only about uniqueness).

The construction / initialization of hashOf follows directly.

2) create a third hash map Integer -> Message (say, "gathered"), initially empty

```
gathered : Integer -> Message
```

**Online phase**

3) as you read and parse your input into messages from each "datagram" of that stream, one after the other, just "compute" (in fact, a mere lookup):

```
key = hashOf[message]
```

and put that (key, message) into gathered, if key isn't already present in there. Clearly, both key lookup and insertion times in gathered will be O(1) and without collision on inserts ever (thanks to gathered's use of an integer key) as a bonus.

You can simply keep track in a local variable (or instance member, if your stream processing is stateful because of other requirements) of the last pair (key, message) that you *had to* insert in gathered (because of encountering that key / message for the first time, at that point in the stream).

**Results**

4) when you are done reading the stream, gathered has all those of your "special messages" that were read and recognized throughout the entire stream, and that you can then enumerate with:

(Pseudo code)

```
for each (key in gathered) {
    message = mapBy[key]
    // do something with message...
}
```

Naturally, you will also know if you spotted all possible / known messages, in gathered, if and only if:

```
count(gathered) == count(mapBy) ( == count(hashOf) )
```

or if that's only a subset of those, otherwise.

Finally, of course, if your corpus of possible messages is a lot richer / larger than a "small enough" finite set of "string constants" (and thus cannot fit in memory to cache mapBy and hashOf), but can still be matched unambiguously as a word of some (regular or context free) language (e.g., string regexes, one per "message type"), you'll likely go for a variant alike:

(In signature notation)

```
mapBy : Integer -> Regex

hashOf : Regex -> Integer
```

and

```
gathered : Regex -> List of Message
```

while step (3) becomes:

(Pseudo code)

```
regex = find the first regex (e.g., in mapBy) that matches message // details omitted
if (regex == null) {
    throw error
}
if (regex in gathered (as a key)) {
    list = gathered[regex] // meaning: lookup list of message, by regex
} else {
    list = new list of message
    gathered[regex] = list // meaning: add (regex, list) to gathered
}
if (not message in list) {
    add message to list
    last = message
}
```

Ref.

Perfect hash:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function

'HTH,